# search string in a text file

Tags: android

I want to search for a name of a co ordinate in a text file and then use the x and y values.
I did the programming in Java ready to program and there it works fine, but when I use the same method in eclipse it gives me the last co ordinates name with no x and y

Here is the code:

```
    coordsuk1 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etJoin1);
    searchco1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.bSearchCo1);
    searchco1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                File myfile=new File("/sdcard/"+filename.getText().toString()+".txt");
                FileInputStream filein=new FileInputStream(myfile);
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(filein));

                String reel = br.readLine ();

                                int tel = reel.indexOf (" ");
                                naamsuk1 = reel.substring (0, tel);

                   while (!naamsuk1.equals (coordsuk1))
                   {

                          reel = br.readLine ();
                          tel = reel.indexOf (" ");
                          naamsuk1 = reel.substring (0, tel);
                   }

                   coordnaam1join = reel.substring (0, tel);
                   coordy1 = Double.parseDouble (reel.substring (10, 22));
                   coordx1 = Double.parseDouble (reel.substring (26, 36));

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Co ord '"+filename.getText().toString()+"' found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            joinIntv1.setText("coordsuk1: "+coordsuk1);
            joinIntv2.setText("naamsuk1: "+naamsuk1);

                            joinIntv3.setText("coordy1: "+coordy1);
            joinIntv4.setText("coordx1: "+coordx1);


        }
    });
```

o and I get a blank Toast.
The text file looks like this:

AB -42537.4098 24263.8160

ST4 -42677.9017 24201.6750

WODRC -42428.8129 24151.9450

MGDM -42369.8561 24128.2079

Comment: are you getting coordinates correctly ?

Comment: only gives me the last name MGDM

Comment: what is naamsuk1 ? String or EditText ?

Comment: coordsuk1 is not string object. how you can compare naamsuk1 and coordsuk1 ?? just verify it.

Comment: I got it right last night. I used this "while (!naamsuk1.equals (coordsuk1.getText().toString()))" and this                       "File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File file = new File(sdcard,filename.getText().toString()+".txt");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));". Now it work perfect.